# How to Convert image format on MAC

Tags: macos, qt, applescript

I am work on MAC ,I want to convert .bmp and .JPEG file to .PDF file format on mac machine using Qt or APplescript. My operating system version is 10.6 .

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that OSX has command line utility useful for exactly this sort of thing called [sips](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html).  I'm posting this in a different answer, as this is a completely different approach than the UI scripting in my other answer.

You can create a little wrapper shell script to do what you need:

```
#!/bin/bash

sips -s format pdf "$1" --out "${1%.*}.pdf"
```

Save this as e.g img2pdf, then give it execute permissions:

```
chmod +x img2pdf
```

Then you can use the following command to do your conversions:

```
./img2pdf.txt "/Users/mmouse/Desktop/Screen Shot 2013-07-22 at 9.00.36 AM.png"
```

If you really don't want this in a shell script and must have an Applescript, then you can call the relevant commands from an Applescript:

```
set ImgFile to "/Users/mmouse/Desktop/Screen Shot 2013-07-22 at 9.00.36 AM.png"

do shell script "imgfile=" & quoted form of ImgFile & " ; sips -s format pdf \"$imgfile\" --out \"${imgfile%.*}.pdf\""
```

As a point of interest, if you needed to do the opposite, i.e. convert .pdf to .png, then the [Image Events scripting extension](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/imageevents/08.html) in OSX can do this easily:

```
set ImgFile to "/Users/mmouse/Desktop/Screen Shot 2013-07-18 at 2.52.47 PM.pdf"
tell application "Image Events"
    set Img to open file ImgFile
    save Img as PNG
end tell
```

But unfortunately, the Image Events scripting extension only allows PDF files to be read and not written, so is not useful in your specific situation.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for replay ,In your script image conversion png to pdf is successfully.but Image event class for apple script do not convert pdf to png.when I am run this apple script ,your script is damaged to .pdf file.

Comment: My next question is ,How to convert .jpeg image in to ICNS,TGA,GIF,exr and raw format.If possible then please replay me.

Comment: I think these are more specialised formats - It looks like sips can also write .TGA files, but the rest probably need third-party image manipulation software.  I would ask another question, perhaps including the [image] and perhaps [image-manipulation] and [image-processing] tags

Comment: Ok,but I do not want depend on third party software.If you are assign another script(or API) which convert  JPEG and bmp file into Raw format(CR2,CEW,NEF,SR2,X3F,ORf,ARW,SRF).If possible then replay me.

Comment: My next another question is ,hot to rotate image without changing the background color and image size is not change.

Comment: hi, do shell script command convert to jpeg image into TGA,GIF,PDF etc. but jpeg image format is not converted to Quick time image(qtif),pict and SGi format.In this case script command is successfully run but image is not save in destination path.

Comment: Please ask your follow-up questions as new questions with more detail of what you need and what you have tried, and appropriate tagging.  I don't think I have the answers to any of these, but perhaps others will.

Comment: Image Events can do some [image rotation](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/imageevents/03.html) - not sure if this is sufficient for your needs or not.  Please ask a new question with more detail.  It would be helpful if you could post before and after examples of the rotation you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

There's a "New PDF from Images" automator action... so just use the automator workflow.

Comment: ok ,but I am not use automator action with programing .  Send me script which use in program.

Answer (score 0):

This can be written much more elegantly, but here is a quick [UI element script](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/) to drive the Preview application to do this.

Set `ImgFile` to whatever filename you like - You can modify the script so this can be passed a parameter.

```
set ImgFile to "/Users/mmouse/Desktop/Screen Shot 2013-07-18 at 2.52.47 PM.png"
do shell script "open -a Preview " & quoted form of ImgFile
tell application "Preview"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    -- turn on UI automation - may throw a permissions dialog
    if UI elements enabled is false then
        set UI elements enabled to true
    end if
    click menu item "Export…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "Preview"
    delay 1 -- sigh - wait for window to open
    click pop up button 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of application process "Preview"
    click menu item "PDF" of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of application process "Preview"
    click UI element "Save" of sheet 1 of window 1 of application process "Preview"
    click menu item "Close Window" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "Preview"
end tell
```

In general, these keywords let the script interact directly with specific elements of a program's user interface.  Search google for "applescript ui scripting" - there are several good pages on this topic.

For example:

```
click menu item "Export…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "Preview"
```

This line literally clicks on the "Export…" item in the "File" menu of the "Preview" application.  Thus the "Export…" dialog box gets opened up.  The remaining lines then interact with that dialog to export the image to a .pdf file.

I believe the script, as written should do the image conversion to a .pdf in the same folder, exactly as you want it to do.

If you want to do more UI scripting, the record function in the Automator application is very handy - you can literally select and copy recorded steps from this application and paste them into the Applescript Editor, where they will appear as equivalent applescript elements.  Also the UI Element Inspector or Accessibility Inspector (in xcode) are very useful for figuring out the UI structure of a given application you wish to control.

Comment: ok, thanks ,but i am not understand the click menu,pop up,UI element ,group keywords. My main concern is ,In this script ImgFile path is source path, I want to convert this image into pdf file format to same path.

Comment: I have added some more to my answer, but I really believe this script, as written should do the image conversion to a .pdf in the same folder, exactly as you want it to do.  At least it works on my machine.

Comment: In this script, through error on click menu item line . see the screen shot.

Comment: In this script, Source file is successfully preview but click menu item statement for script through error.                                can you give me any script which convert .pdf file without any popup dialog.

Comment: What version of OSX and Preview are you using?  I am using OSX 10.8.4 and Preview 6.0.1 (756.6).  Do you see an export option in the File menu of the Preview app?  If so, I suspect the "..." in the script is getting translated during copy/paste incorrectly.  But I have a much simpler answer for you coming up...